# model.predict gives different outputs when data fed using generator and numpy array

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using a trained model to predict values. But getting different answers when using a generator and a numpy array.(the accuracies are 10%, 70%)

[Colab Notebook:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dlE0dsKIPu5fkt1ChieRrH58z0Gxvraj?usp=sharing)

There are two cases

Case 1: Here i am feeding the data using a custom made generator and got prediction say X

Case 2: Here i am collecting the data from generator storing it in a numpy array and after prediction got prediction Y.

why is this happening?

P.S: Generator does not shuffle and i am resetting it.

Comment: Have you tried plotting / visualizing both inputs to confirm they are the same? Maybe one method rotates the input because it goes by rows and the other by columns?

Comment: row order in which input are fed is same in both cases. I dont understand what do you mean by rotation of input because it goes by column? @Zoe

Comment: When it reads in the data, it will either read it row by row, or column by column. This is why when using R (maybe also python?) you need to use `array_reshape()` on the data: https://rdrr.io/cran/reticulate/man/array_reshape.html. If you read one file row by row, and another one column by column, you accidentally rotate the input. But it's only a guess.

Comment: @zoe the generator i have written feeds the data row by row so this is not the issue.

Comment: Which accuracy do you assume to be correct? I guess the one not using the generator? Have you tried using model.evaluate() instead of manually getting predictions and truth? And what happens if you reset the generator again before collecting the "truth"? Since your accuracy using the generator is bad, I guess your labels and inputs don't match...

Comment: model.evaluate gives same accuracy as when not using generator. 
i have tried resetting the generator still same behavior in case of model.predict
only model.predict gives different output in two cases.
i need output from model.predict to calculate precision and recall.

Comment: @zoe no its not beaacuse when i manually accumulate data from generator save it as numpy array and then pass it on to model.predict and then manually calculate accuracy it comes correct.